# Ajax Request every time when change date

Tags: ajax

I try to create ajax which send date every time when change date and place in html the response and then if all input is send then submit. How to create script which listen the fields if is changed.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <legend></legend>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="reservation_Date">Date</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="reservation_Date"
                               name="reservation[date]">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="reservation_Time">Time</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="time" class="form-control" id="reservation_Time"
                               name="reservation[time]">
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
                        <a class="btn btn-default" href="">Cancel</a>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Reservation!</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Request data</button>

                <p id="reserved"></p>

                <script>

                    function loadDoc() {
                        var Date = $('#reservation_date').val();
                        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                                document.getElementById("reserved").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                            }
                        };
                        xhttp.open("POST", "/create", true);
                        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                        xhttp.send(Date);
                    }
                </script>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

I try with this script and I add this in the input  onchange="mySubmit(this.dateTime)" and now when I change the date give me the same form again.

```
<script>
                    function mySubmit(reservation_Date) {
                        $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
                            data: $("reservation_Date").serialize(), // get the form data
                            type: $(reservation_Date).attr("POST"), // GET or POST
                            url: $(reservation_Date).attr("/create"), // the file to call
                            success: function (response) { // on success..
                                $('#demo').html(response); // update the DIV
                            }
                        });
                    }
                </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution

```
onchange="mySubmit(this.input)"

<script>
            function mySubmit() {
                var Date = document.getElementById("reservation_Date").value;
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    }
                };
                xhttp.open("POST", "/check", true);
                xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xhttp.send(Date);
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: You should accept this answer unless you also seek perhaps "better" answers and if so add a note to that effect.